# Vertical align not working?

Tags: css

I want to center the text to be in the middle of a cell of an 'artificial' table I have created. (Artificial because it uses divs)

In the css style I added these lines:

```
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Which normally do the trick. In this case, however they don't.  Here is the entire source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>

    <title>asd</title>
    <style>
        body {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }  
     .Table {
       position:absolute;
       left:25px;
       top:275px;
       border:none;
       width:650px;
       height:40.99999px;
       border-top:1px solid black;
       border-left:1px solid black;
}
.Cell {
    float:left;
    width:107.3333px;
    height:40px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;

    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}       
    </style>
</head>

<body>  
      <div class="Table">
         <div class="Cell ">Hello</div>
         <div class="Cell ">Hello</div>
         <div class="Cell ">hihi</div>         
          <div class="clear"></div>
         <div class="Cell "></div>
         <div class="Cell "></div>
         <div class="Cell "></div>
      </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post it to a Fiddle (jsfiddle.net)... this way it would be easier to help :-)

Comment: Vertical align [applies to inline-level and table-cell elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vertical-align` doesn't work on block elements (divs), in your case you can use `line-height: 40px;` instead. Giving a text element a line-height equal to the parent's height will center it verically

Comment: Thank you, the edit cleared the my questions. I will mark this as an answer when the timer expires

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` does not work for `div` , it works for table cell

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
 display:table-cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Add property `display:table-cell;` for it to work

Answer (score 0):

use this css

tou should use `display:table;` and `display:table-cell`;property

http://jsfiddle.net/MepnV/

```
 body {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
        }  
     .Table {
       position:absolute;
       left:25px;
       top:275px;
       border:none;
       width:650px;
    display:table;
       height:40.99999px;
       border-top:1px solid black;
       border-left:1px solid black;
}
.Cell {

    width:107.3333px;
    height:40px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the height in pixels for the `.cell` class so you can do the following:

Add `line-height: 40px;` to the `.cell` selector in your CSS.